# line-height no me hace mas alto el elemento en elementos inline a diferencia de si lo uso con elementos block

Tags: html, css

```css
.line-height{
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-height-container">
  <div class="line-height">hola mundo</div>
<div>
```

```css
.line-height-container{
   background-color: pink;
}

.line-height{
   line-height: 2em;
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="line-height-container">
      <span class="line-height">hola mundo</span>
 <div>
```

¿porque en elementos en linea la caja no crece por el alto de la linea si no que la linea se desborda y porque en elementos en bloque, si el alto del texto crece, el contenedor lo hace también para cubrir a todo el texto y su alto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por que el texto no puede tener altura ni ancho, por eso crece el line-height pero no el background.
y en este problema en especifico, como el contenedor padre no tiene ni ancho ni altura, toma este valor como automatico, que automaticamente agarra el valor de lo que tenga adentro.

por ejemplo si haces bloque el texto y le das altura y ancho se agranda

```css
.line-height-container{
   background-color: pink;
}

.line-height{
display:block;
    width:90px;
    height:60px;
   line-height: 2em;
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="line-height-container">
      <span class="line-height">hola mundo</span>
 <div>
```

Lo mismo si lo haces pequeño

```css
.line-height-container{
   background-color: pink;
}

.line-height{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
   line-height: 2em;
   background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="line-height-container">
      <span class="line-height">hola mundo</span>
 <div>
```

Comment: ya veo, crei que el line height al ser parte del texto aplicaría con el comportamiento de inline, porque los inline crecen con su contenido y al ser line-height parte del texto como tal creí que inline debería tener efecto, ajustándose al texto y su altura, pero no, entonces los inline se ajustan al texto pero si se agrega line-height, es como que se quiera aumentar el alto de la caja